# WIX Uninstall not running elevated

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have a WIX project that I have designated with InstallPrivilege="elevated" in the Package. that works fine. However, the uninstall complains that it cannot delete the registry key. How do I get the unstall to ask for elevated privileges as well?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you need delete registrykey? Then use [RemoveRegistryKey Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removeregistrykey.html). In action set *removeOnUninstall* and other attributes.

Comment: I do not believe it is that easy since it requires elevated privilege. I would prefer to just have Wix prompt for elevated privilege the same as they do for Install.

Comment: i also have `InstallPrivileges="elevated"`, it means you run installer **WITH** higher (elevated) privileges. So yeah i've got this too, and it easy remove all registry keys without problem. Btw. i wonder how u do your registrykeys, because it should remove it automaticly